# Uniform Topology, Product Topology and Box Topology comparison

Tags: general-topology

There’s a theorem in Munkres Topology that says that the on $R^J$ uniform topology is finer than the product topology and coarser than the box topology and they are all different when the index set $J$ is infinite. And in the theorem he chooses an open set in the product topology $\prod U_\alpha$,where $U_\alpha$ is different from $R$ only for finitely many indices. Isn’t this contradicting the statement of the theorem? He says that they are all different only for the infinite cases and considers an infinite case here. Am I missing something? Another question is can someone give an example of an arbitrary index set? How does it look like, can it be countably infinite?

Comment: An example of a countable index set is the naturals, and for uncountable you can try indexing an operation over the reals.

Answer (score 1):

**First part**

Let's denote these three topologies by $\tau_u,\tau_p,\tau_b$.
Let's separate the conclusion of Theorem 20.4:

- For any set of indices we have $\tau_p\subseteq \tau_u\subseteq \tau_b$.
- For an infinite set of indices we have $\tau_p \neq \tau_u\neq \tau_b$.
- For a finite set of indices we have $\tau_p = \tau_u = \tau_b$.

The proof concerns only the first case, so we have to consider a general case (finitely many indices or not). The second part is left for the reader. The third part follows from the first part and previous considerations ($\tau_p = \tau_b$ for a finite case).

**Second part**

Any set can be used as an index set. For example:

- $a_{m,n}=\frac{mn}{m^2+n^2}$, $m,n\in\Bbb N$.
- $U_{r}=(r,\infty)$ for $r\in\Bbb R$.
- $U_{c,r} = B(c,r) = \{x\in X\,|\, d(x,c)<r\}$ for any $c\in X,r>0$.
- $X_\alpha = \Bbb R$ for $\alpha\leq\Omega$ (first uncountable ordinal number).
- $A_{x,y}=$ interval on a plane joining $(0,0)$ with $(x,y)$ for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$.